# Upload on server via php error

Tags: php, image, mysqli, upload

I'm trying to create an upload form in which i can load an image and then the path of the image will be saved on the database. Of course, not working so far!! This is the code i use:

```
<?php
include("db_connect.php");

    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     }



if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "images/".$imagename;


if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {

    $query_upload="INSERT into 'walls' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES ('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
    mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());  

}else{

   exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
} 

}

?>
<h1>Image UPLOADER</h1>
<form action="uploader.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<input name="uploadedimage" type="file">
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input name="Upload Now" type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</td>
</tr>


</tbody></table>

</form>
```

the db_connect.php

```
<?php

    $sql_servername = "localhost";
    $sql_user = "***";
    $sql_pass = "***";
    $sql_db_name = "***";

    // connect to mysql server
    $db = new mysqli($sql_servername, $sql_user, $sql_pass, $sql_db_name);
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
    }

?>
```

Of course i can't show the credentials but i'm sure at 100% that are correct and there aren't the problem! When i try to upload i get the message:

```
Error While uploading image on the server
```

But i can't understand why and how could i solve. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: you should `print_r($_FILES)` for debugging reasons. I suspect it will have an error. PHP returns an appropriate error code along with the file array, please take a look at this site to see all possible errors: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: mmh i tried to print print_r($_FILES) but nothing appears...is it normal?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: ok wait now printing appears this: `Array ( [uploadedimage] => Array ( [name] => icona.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpARtAYu [error] => 0 [size] => 25916 ) ) Array`

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)` should at least print an empty array. Even if error_reporting is disabled. Did you do it before your exit?

Comment: Ah sorry, the msg is shown if move_uploaded_file fails. You should really enable error_reporting for debugging. I suspect a file permission problem or a wrong target path.

Comment: ok the error seems here: `if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path))` and the error is: `Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpzjfgHY' to 'images/14-05-2015-1431645827.png'`

Comment: try to do chmod 777 on images folder after checking if images folder exists. And it is always a good idea to work with absolute paths.

Comment: Ok wait, i think we're so close... now i have this error `Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` i set the folder to 777 and i'm as root...why i can't insert if i already have the permissions??

Comment: Ah by the way, now it works the upload on server but not the database insert

Comment: db_connect.php is using mysqli(), but your mail file is using the deprecated mysql_query() function

Comment: yes, fixed..now i use mysqli to insert..but i get `error in INSERT into 'walls' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES ('/var/www/html/images/14-05-2015-1431646521.png','2015-05-14')` -.-" could be the timestamp maybe the problem?

Comment: this is new error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''images_path','submission_date') VALUES ('/var/www/html/images/14-05-2015-143' at line 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$query_upload = "INSERT INTO walls (images_path, submission_date) VALUES ('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
```

You shouldn't surround your table/column names in quotes, if you do want to, you should use backticks, but this isn't required.

Then alter your query to use either OOP:

```
$db->query($query_upload) or die($db->error);
```

Or procedural style:

```
mysqli_query($db, $query_upload) or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Instead of the deprecated mysql_query() function.

Comment: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters.. something is wrong

Comment: i added $db in the mysqli_query param... now i have this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''images_path','submission_date') VALUES ('/var/www/html/images/14-05-2015-143' at line 1`

Comment: @End.Game now you can see the error that makes solving this much easier. I've edited my answer, but you should consider using a prepared statement instead, I haven't posted how to do this as I personally use PDO and it probably goes beyond the scope of your question.